# Allow user to send multiple's user to email via one function laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
function sendEmail($user_id){

    $ids = Input::get('system_id');
    DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $send = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('user_id', $ids)->get();  

    $mainUser = User::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
    foreach($send as $value) {

        $data = [
                    'master_name'  => $mainUser['name'],
                    'master_id'  => $mainUser->user_id,
                    'name'     => $value->name,
                    'email'    => $value['email'],
                    'link_confirmation_code'  => $value['link_confirmation_code']       
                ];

        }

        Mail::later(5, 'emails.send.confirm-user', $data, function($message) use ($emails, $names)
                {
                    $message->from('no-reply@myemail.com', 'Myemail');
                    $message->to($emails, $names)->subject('Yes - connect us');
                });

}

In blade


Hi {{$name}},

<td>{{$master_name}} has requested you to connect with us!</td>

<a href="{{ URL::to('v1/register/' . $link_confirmation_code) }}">Connect</a>
```

I expect each user should get email along with main_user and each user have confirmation_link that allow him/her to verifying the same. Applied code but does work only for single/first user not for others. please suggest

Comment: Have a checked error log OR may be some issue with other email, first try with `send()` to check it's working fine?

Comment: Email is working fine going to each user but same it should different i.e Hi {{$name}}, and <a href="{{ URL::to('v1/register/' . $link_confirmation_code) }}">Connect</a>

Comment: So what if you put `Mail::send` into loop? It should work

Comment: I also noticed that you haven't defined `$emails' & `$names`?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => shaqulla.looky@sss.com
)
Array
(
    [0] => shaqulla.looky@sss.com
    [1] => vmohosova@dss.com
)

Comment: $emails prints this. This mean emails is sending to these array but look like there is duplicate that cause it is sending to twice time to     [0] => shaqulla.looky@sss.com

Comment: How can i prevent i use array_unique but did not work

Comment: np, we will resolved it, just let me know you need to go with `Mail::send`?

Comment: Correct I gone through with Mail::send

Comment: I've place the answer with code correction, Have a look @Amy

Comment: Okay let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you just trying send the mail using dynamic looping without delay operation. If this is correct, follow below code:

**In controller:**

```
function sendEmail($user_id){

    $ids = Input::get('system_id');
    DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $send = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('user_id', $ids)->get();  

    $mainUser = User::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
    foreach($send as $value) {

        //Variable initializaation and setup operation...
        $toEmail = $value->email;
        $toName = $value->name;
        $link_confirmation_code = url('v1/register/', [$link_confirmation_code]);
        $data = [
                    'master_name'  => $mainUser['name'],
                    'master_id'  => $mainUser->user_id,
                    'name'     => toName,
                    'email'    => $toEmail,
                    'link_confirmation_code'  => $link_confirmation_code       
                ];

        //Mail sendting operation...
        Mail::send('emails.send.confirm-user', $data, function($message) use($toEmail, $toName) {
            $message->from('no-reply@myemail.com', 'Myemail');
            $message->to($toEmail, $toName)->subject('Yes - connect us');
        });
    }
}
```

**In Blade:**

```
Hi {{$name}},

<td>{{$master_name}} has requested you to connect with us!</td>

<a href="{{$link_confirmation_code}}">Connect</a>
```

Just check that `$toEmail` and `$toName`, as there is no definition given so place it as assumption.

Comment: Excellent that make sense for me as well thanks i'll use in my code will check